Suddenly get 200 lines of firebase errors
Everything was working great. Then I walked away and when I came back I get THIS when I try running my app. I set breakpoints, and it doesn't appear to be getting to my main routine.
start of error output
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.14.0/lib/src/screens/internal/multi_provider_screen.dart:25:14: Error: A value of type 'List<AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>>?' can't be returned from a function with return type 'List<AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>>' because 'List<AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>>?' is nullable and 'List<AuthProvider<AuthListener, AuthCredential>>' isn't.
 - 'List' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'AuthProvider' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.14.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthListener' is from 'package:firebase_ui_auth/src/providers/auth_provider.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_ui_auth-1.14.0/lib/src/providers/auth_provider.dart').
 - 'AuthCredential' is from 'package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/auth_credential.dart' ('../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_auth_platform_interface-7.1.8/lib/src/auth_credential.dart').
      return _providers;
             ^

end of error output
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/vm_service-13.0.0/lib/src/vm_service.dart:314:30: Context: '_disposeHandler' couldn't be promoted because field promotion is only available in Dart 3.2 and above.
See http://dart.dev/go/non-promo-field-promotion-unavailable
  late final DisposeHandler? _disposeHandler;
                             ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Flutter-Dart\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Here's what I tried so far w/o success:

pub get/update
flutter clean and rebuild
exit project, restart Windows
deleted the project and pulled a known good copy from github (still get same error!)


I am so confused! I uninstalled everything, and re-installed flutter jellyfish. I created a default Flutter application, and even IT won't compile. The errors are different, but there are still a lot of them. flutter doctor returns all checkmarks. Now the first error is ../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/collection-1.18.0/lib/src/canonicalized_map.dart:173:60: Error: Can't use an expression of type 'bool Function(K)?' as a function because it's potentially null.
Try calling using ?.call instead.
(key is K) && (_isValidKeyFn == null || _isValidKeyFn(key));

Is there a good way short of wiping my hard drive (which is actually not a big deal - i do it regularly anyway) to clear every last bit of flutter, dart, android studio, the SDKs, etc. from the system to start clean? Its failing on my Windows 11 system. Everything runs fine on my second Mac system.

I needed to get moving on this, so I reformatted the drive, re-installed Windows and Android Project, pulled down my project and everything works fine again.
